# Iteration problem

Tags: list-manipulation, formatting

I am trying to write a simple program - perform `f1` as long as `t` is smaller than 800. `t` is declared in `a` list. The problem is easy, but difficult to explain, so I'll give You my code:

```
a = {t -> 120};
f1[{x_, y_}] := {x + t, y + t} /. a;
NestWhile[f1[#] &; a = a /. Rule[t, _] :> Rule[t, f1[#][[1]] &], {100, 100}, (t /. a) <= 800]
```

> ReplaceAll::reps: {{t->(f1[Slot[<<1>>]][[1]]&)}>=800} is neither a list of replacement 
>       rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>

After each calculation step I want to change replacement rule in `a` list. Desired output should be `{880, 880}`. Any idea how to make it work? I know it sounds like a stupid example, but if can fix that, I can also fix problem with my original functions.

Comment: As a first observation, the condition `t /. a <= 800` in my opinion should read `(t /. a) <= 800`. Secondly it is not clear to me what is the function to be nested. It appears you are trying to nest a replacement rule.

Comment: 1. My bad, I'll correct that. 2.If nesting a replacement rule means updating the value assigned to `t` after each step, than yes

Comment: I remember the other post where you wanted to update a replacement rule but... is it really necessary? Would you not be better off with a more straightforward approach as in `f[{{x_, y_}, t_}] := {{x + t, y + t}, x + t}; NestList[f, {{100, 100}, 120}, 10]`, for example?

Comment: As I am just beginning with _Mathematica_, I may be prone to sticking with certain ideas, which may not be the best ones. Changing a replacement rule over an iteration process was so far my best idea to solve my problem, but I'll try it with `t` inside the function. Thanks for advice!

Comment: The first argument of `Nest` *must* be a function.  This function may have side effect and change global variables, but it still must be a function.  This is why your example fails.  The last argument of `NestWhile` also needs to be a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find, when using iterators such a `NestList`, that it is a good idea to preserve the full state of the iteration at each step. Applying that principle to your calculation, I came up with this:

```
f1[{{x_, y_}, r_}] := Module[{v}, {v = {x + t, y + t} /. r, t -> v[[1]]}]
First @ NestWhile[f1, {{100, 100}, t -> 120}, #[[1, 1]] <= 800 &]
```

> {880, 880}

#### Update

Since Wojciech Sitkiewicz has opened up his question to allow other iterators than `NestList`, I suggest a very simple approach using `While`.

```
f1[{x_, y_}] := Module[{bn}, bn = {x + t, y + t} /. a; a = t -> bn[[1]]; bn]
a = t -> 120; pair = {100, 100};
While[(pair = f1[pair])[[1]] <= 800]
pair
```

> {880, 880}

Answer (score 1):

Since function `f1` in my question operated on a list consisting of two variables, changing it into a nested list may not always be convenient, while it may force changes in other parts of the program. I forgot to stress it in the question, nevertheless I allowed myself to modify m_goldberg's solution a little bit, so that `f1` argument form remains the same as in question.

```
a = {t -> 120};
f1[{x_, y_}] := Module[{bn}, bn = {x + t, y + t} /. a;
a = a /. Rule[t, _] :> Rule[t, bn[[1]]]; bn]

Catch[Nest[If[#[[1]] > 800, Throw[#], f1[#]] &, {100, 100}, 5]]
```

> {880, 880}

I asked about `NestWhile[]`, but it seems one can solve this problem also using `Nest[]`, `Catch[]` and `Throw[]`. The only flaw of this solution is that one have to predict (more or less) how many `Nest` operations will be executed before `Throw` is encountered. 
I'm not sure whether it is the best way to solve this in *Mathematica*, but so far for me it's working.